# How to amend older Git commit?

Tags: git, version-control, git-rewrite-history

I have made 3 git commits, but have not been pushed.
How can I amend the older one (ddc6859af44) and (47175e84c) which is not the most recent one?

```
$git log
commit f4074f289b8a49250b15a4f25ca4b46017454781
Date:   Tue Jan 10 10:57:27 2012 -0800

commit ddc6859af448b8fd2e86dd0437c47b6014380a7f
Date:   Mon Jan 9 16:29:30 2012 -0800

commit 47175e84c2cb7e47520f7dde824718eae3624550
Date:   Mon Jan 9 13:13:22 2012 -0800
```

Comment: Please clarify if you want to combine those 2 commits into 1 commit or if you want to amend each one with further changes.

Comment: I've created a Bash script for this exact purpose: github.com/colinodell/git-amend-old Once installed, you'd use it like this: `git amend-old abcd123`, where `abcd123` is the old commit you want to amend with your staged changes. Hope somebody finds it useful!

Answer (score 295):

```
git rebase -i HEAD^^^
```

Now mark the ones you want to amend with `edit` or `e` (replace `pick`). Now save and exit.

Now make your changes, then

```
git add .
git rebase --continue
```

If you want to add an extra delete remove the options from the commit command. If you want to adjust the message, omit just the `--no-edit` option.

Comment: It may be convenient to use `git stash` or `git stash [-p|--patch]` (interactive) to easily apply the changes to an older commit during a rebase.

Comment: Note - you don't have to git commit after git add -A, simply git rebase --continue will keep your changes.

Comment: `no matches found: HEAD^^^`

Comment: @kleinfreund You've probably solved that after two years, but for anyone else (like me) with that problem: some shells (like zsh) parse `^` as a pattern. You can use `~` instead in that case.

Comment: What does the triple ^ do?

Comment: You can escape the ^ with a /. Each ^ means parent and implies first parent. ^ is the same as ^1. Look up "treeish" in the git manual. ~ is a way of shortening a few ^ together. ^^^ and ~3 are equivalent.

Comment: @DarkFranX "HEAD^^^" means "3 commits before head"

Comment: Alternatively, `git rebase -i HEAD~N` to go last N commits back (saves having to type multiple `^`)

Comment: So you can either keep adding ^ to get more commits (my amend I needed to do was 4 behind. So I did HEAD^^^^)

Answer (score 200):

I prepared my commit that I wanted to amend with an older one and was surprised to see that rebase -i complained that I have uncommitted changes. But I didn't want to make my changes again specifying edit option of the older commit. So the solution was pretty easy and straightforward:

1. prepare your update to older commit, add it and commit
2. `git rebase -i <commit you want to amend>^` - notice the `^` so you see the said commit in the text editor
3. you will get sometihng like this:

   ```
   pick 8c83e24 use substitution instead of separate subsystems file to avoid jgroups.xml and jgroups-e2.xml going out of sync
   pick 799ce28 generate ec2 configuration out of subsystems-ha.xml and subsystems-full-ha.xml to avoid discrepancies
   pick e23d23a fix indentation of jgroups.xml
   ```
4. now to combine e23d23a with 8c83e24 you can change line order and use squash like this:

   ```
   pick 8c83e24 use substitution instead of separate subsystems file to avoid jgroups.xml and jgroups-e2.xml going out of sync    
   squash e23d23a fix indentation of jgroups.xml
   pick 799ce28 generate ec2 configuration out of subsystems-ha.xml and subsystems-full-ha.xml to avoid discrepancies
   ```
5. write and exit the file, you will be present with an editor to merge the commit messages. Do so and save/exit the text document
6. You are done, your commits are amended

credit goes to: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History
There's also other useful demonstrated git magic.

Comment: I didn't realize I could reorder the lines in the rebase file. Great tip!

Comment: if anyone is unfamiliar with the vi commands to edit a file in the terminal, this page is a very good reference https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html

Comment: @DanBechard be careful when you reorder lines: if you accidentally cut and forget to paste: that commit is gone!!

Comment: Use just `git rebase -i` to see all commits in your branch. What you want most of the time :)

Answer (score 24):

I've used another way for a few times. In fact, it is a manual `git rebase -i`. It is useful when you want to rearrange several commits including squashing or splitting some of them. The main advantage is that you don't have to decide about every commit's destiny at a single moment. You'll also have all Git features available during the process unlike during a rebase. For example, you can display the log of both original and rewritten history at any time, or even do another rebase!

I'll refer to the commits in the following way, so it's readable easily:

```sh
C # good commit after a bad one
B # bad commit
A # good commit before a bad one
```

Your history in the beginning looks like this:

```
x - A - B - C
|           |
|           master
|
origin/master
```

We'll recreate it this way:

```
x - A - B*- C'
|           |
|           master
|
origin/master
```

## Procedure

```sh
git checkout B       # get working-tree to the state of the commit B
git reset --soft A   # tell Git that we are working before the commit B
git checkout -b rewrite-history  # create a new branch for alternative history
```

Improve your old commit using `git add` (`git add -i`, `git stash` etc.) now. You can even split your old commit into two or more.

```sh
git commit           # recreate commit B (result = B*)
git cherry-pick C    # copy C to our new branch (result = C')
```

Intermediate result:

```
x - A - B - C 
|    \      |
|     \     master
|      \
|       B*- C'
|           |
|           rewrite-history
|
origin/master
```

Let's finish:

```sh
git checkout master
git reset --hard rewrite-history  # make this branch master
```

Or using just one command:

```sh
git branch -f master  # make this place the new tip of the master branch
```

That's it, you can `push` your progress now.

The last task is to delete the temporary branch:

```
git branch -d rewrite-history
```

Comment: wow best answer - it helped me so much!

Comment: BEST answer!!! This is the first time I've completely understood how to modify existed commits. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 20):

You could can use `git rebase` to rewrite the commit history. This can be potentially destructive to your changes, so use with care.

First commit your "amend" change as a normal commit. Then do an interactive rebase starting on the parent of your oldest commit

```
git rebase -i 47175e84c2cb7e47520f7dde824718eae3624550^
```

This will fire up your editor with all commits. Reorder them so your "amend" commit comes below the one you want to amend. Then replace the first word on the line with the "amend" commit with `s` which will combine (**s** quash) it with the commit before. Save and exit your editor and follow the instructions.

Comment: He does not want to squash or reorder the commits.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk: Where does he say that? Btw, your answer also suggests rewriting the history.

Comment: he just wants to amend. no mention of squashing commits together or reordering them.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk: amending is a short-hand for committing & squashing the last two commits. Both change the commit SHA1 ("rewrite history"). Please educate me if I have a wrong mental picture.

Comment: you can amend both commits. Squashing is squashing. Amending is something else.

Comment: I've added a comment on the question requesting clarification from the OP. As it reads now, I've interpreted it as him wanting to change those 2 commits and not squash or reorder them.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are confused what amend does. Make a test project and do what I say and what you say and compare.

Comment: amend adds to the last commit - whether you are in a rebase or not. Squash takes 2 existing commits and makes them into 1. What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing that they both result in new tree object which does contain exactly the same content.

Comment: dear God. It's like pulling teeth. Do you think I don't understand how the DAG is structured? Which of the 564 Git questions that I answered in the last 2+ years lead you to believe this? The issue is whether he wants to amend each of the 2 commits, or if he means that he wants to squash them into one. That is the common terminology.

Comment: Don't get upset, you brought up the nitpicking. And that was exactly what led me to believe you didn't understand what git was doing internally.

Comment: I'm not upset. We should have listened to the suggestion and went to chat :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6632/discussion-between-honk-and-adam-dymitruk)

Comment: I found this answer easier to understand.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `git rebase --interactive`, using the `edit` command on the commit you want to amend.

Answer (score 2):

In case the OP wants to squash the 2 commits specified into 1, here is an alternate way to do it without rebasing

```
git checkout HEAD^               # go to the first commit you want squashed
git reset --soft HEAD^           # go to the second one but keep the tree and index the same
git commit --amend -C HEAD@{1}   # use the message from first commit (omit this to change)
git checkout HEAD@{3} -- .       # get the tree from the commit you did not want to touch
git add -A                       # add everything
git commit -C HEAD@{3}           # commit again using the message from that commit
```

The `@{N)` syntax is handy to know as it will allow you to reference the history of where your references were. In this case it's HEAD which represents your current commit.