# modify a previous commit before pull

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-stash

I need to modify a previous commit, applying a saved stash over 2 files which were not present on that commit. I am trying to rebase with "git rebase 0c1192a^" but I get the message "Current branch artists is up to date.".

How can I rebase, make the required changes and amend the commit

Comment: Is it actually the previous commit? Or an older one? Are there any unstaged changes currently?

Comment: Answered before: [how to modify a specified commit in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit-in-git), [how to amend older git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824971/how-to-amend-older-git-commit)

Answer (score 0):

if it is the last commit you need to alter, use [`git commit --amend`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-the-Last-Commit).

- pop your stash
- once happy with the state of your workspace `git add` the modifications so they enter the [stage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#The-Three-States)
- finally `git commit --amend`