# How to modify a specific commit without changing SHA-1 of consecutive commits?

Tags: git, commit

Please assume a branch:

1. `HEAD`
2. `Commit-3`
3. `Commit-2`
4. `Commit-1`

The content of a specific commit, say `Commit-1`, can be modified as elaborated below:

[How to modify a specified commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1186535/3393574)

[How to amend older Git commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8824971/3393574)

Nevertheless, such attempts "**will change the SHA-1 of the commit as well as all children**" as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186549/3393574).

**Question:**

Is it possible to modify `Commit-1` without changing the SHA-1 of the **consecutive commits**? (The SHA-1 of `Commit-1` can be changed.)

Comment: The fact that you *cannot* do this is a feature. It means that someone can GPG-sign a particular tag and thus endorse every commit leading up to and including the one mentioned in that tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is NOT possible to change `Commit-1` without changing the SHA-1 of all child and descendent commits of `Commit-1`.  This is because the SHA-1 of a commit is calculated using the parent commit(s)' SHA-1 as part of the calculation. In Git, changing a commit requires creating new commits for descendants. In your example, the descendants of `Commit-1` are `Commit-2`, `Commit-3` and `HEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that using `git replace <commit> <other commit>`

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace