# How to commit changes on an old commit et put it on top of history

Tags: git

I have several commits *C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4* (the last)

The features added to C4 are aborted for my project.

I got C3 by typing

```
git checkout <commit_id>
```

and made some changes on it

I'm now in a DETACHED mode.

I would like to commit and push C3 modified on top of history

C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> C5 (= C3 modified)

What's the best way to do that ?

Comment: You should never `git checkout <commit_id>` unless you know what you're doing; that (as you rightly say) is a detached head. If you wanted to "undo" C4, you should have done a `git revert` of C4, or even a `git reset` back to C3.

Comment: See also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824971/how-to-amend-older-git-commit, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit

Answer (score 1):

From your current detached HEAD state, you could create a branch, then reset the original feature branch to that new branch:

```
# from detached HEAD
git branch new_feature
git checkout feature
git reset --hard new_feature
git push --force origin feature
```

Note that we have to force push your feature branch, because we have rewritten its history.

However, you also could have completely avoided even going to a detached HEAD state by just nuking the `C4` commit, modifying the `C3` commit, and adding the other commits:

```
# from feature
git reset --hard HEAD~1
# make changes to C3
git commit --amend
# make commits C4 and C5
git push --force origin feature
```

Comment: Thx for answer. In your example "feature" is equal to C4 in my example ? Right ?

Comment: No.  `feature` is the name of your current branch.

Comment: But all the commit (C1 to C4) are already on the same branch. Sorry for my question but I'm a newbee !

Comment: I can't explain any more clearly than I have above without including diagrams for each step, and I don't have time for that now (and it would be too much information for a basic Git question).