# Amending older commit without creating new commits

Tags: git

I am experimenting with Git. I have a file *a.txt* in the repo and 4 commits in my master branch currently. git log:

```
* aabe7d0 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Updated goats
* 57694cf (tag: customerY_release) Updated sheep
* 791b4cb (tag: customerX_release) Updated cows
* e96a52b Added init contents..'
```

I want to amend an older commit ie., change a line in file *a.txt* in the commit *791b4cb*. "cats=10" to "cats=100". This change then should reflect across all commits *791b4cb, 57694cf, aabe7d0* and no new commits should be created in the process, the tree should look same at the end.

I tried the following from reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824971/how-to-amend-older-git-commit](https://stackoverflow.com):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3   // HEAD~2 did not list the commit 791b4cb...
```

Then changed the line in the opened text editor to:

```
edit 791b4cb
pick 57694cf 
pick aabe7d0
```

Saved... and then made the required changes in a.txt "cats=10" to "cats=100"... and then commited.

```
git add a.txt
git commit --amend --no-edit
git rebase --continue
```

But the above process resulted in a different looking tree with new commits added.

```
* f55fdd4 (HEAD -> master) Updated goats
* 59c850d Updated sheep
* 7aee3ea Updated cows
| * aabe7d0 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Updated goats
| * 57694cf (tag: customerY_release) Updated sheep
| * 791b4cb (tag: customerX_release) Updated cows
|/
* e96a52b Added init contents..'
```

This is not what I intended. I wanted the tree looks same as from beginning as if all existing commits: *791b4cb, 57694cf, aabe7d0* get merged and amended across with changes happened in *a.txt* at *791b4cb*... Is it possible to do this in Git?

Comment: `git reset` and `force push`, evils to rewrite history. you will break stuff though.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for doesn't make sense.

In Git, each commit is a record of the filesystem tree **and a pointer to its parent commit**.  If you change the parent of a commit, you're actually constructing a *different* commit.  And then you make copies of the subsequent commit, that again is similar to originals, but with a different parent.  And so on.

If you push (with `--force-with-lease` option), then the upstream tree will once again look like your local tree.  Be careful not to surprise other developers with force-push, though.