# How to amend the second newest commit

Tags: git, github

I know you can do `git --amend` to change the commit message of the latest commit. But how do I change the second newest commit message? Here's what my commit looks like now:

```
commit eca1b2db14da8ace66aed172056c6e7aaf323093
Author: Adam Sandler
Date:   Fri Jul 13 18:00:13 2012 -0700

    Pre-final work on appending new items on top

commit 7d21bbfea24cb72eafbe0213cad6339354078a81
Author: Adam Sandler
Date:   Fri Jul 13 11:57:40 2012 -0700

    Pre-final work on appending new item on top.

    Loading more  when user reaches the end of the scroll view
```

I want to change the commit `7d21bbfea24cb72eafbe0213ca` that has two messages in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I amend a previous git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587880/how-can-i-amend-a-previous-git-commit)

Answer (score 5):

It seems there are always many ways to do things in git, and I'm not an expert, but here's what I do in that situation:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

That brings up an editor with something like:

```
pick eca1b2d Pre-final work on appending new items on top
pick 7d21bbf Pre-final work on appending new item on top.
```

with some instructions below that.  If you change `pick` to `reword` on the commit whose message you'd like to change, then save and exit the editor, you'll have another editor opened where you can reword the commit message.

I only ever do this on commits I haven't pushed yet.  If you've already pushed the commit whose message you're changing, you'll want to read this: [How do I recover/resynchronise after someone pushes a rebase or a reset to a published branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084868/how-do-i-recover-resynchronise-after-someone-pushes-a-rebase-or-a-reset-to-a-pub)

Comment: I've actually merged it with another branch and doing so gives me the commit message from the other commit